# DELETE row in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete records from my database using a form. Can't get this to work. 
Any ideas?

```
include 'newsconnect.php';
$Id = $_POST['Id'];
if (empty($Id) === true {
    echo 'please input an Post ID.';
} else {
    if(!$_POST['Submit']) {
        header('Location: http://www.hidensecrets.yourwebsolution.net/forum.php');
    } else {
        mysql_query("DELETE * FROM forum WHERE id = '$Id'") or die(mysql_error());
        header('Location: http://www.hidensecrets.yourwebsolution.net/forum.php') ;
        echo "Deleted!";        
    }
}
```

I seem to land on this page which displays no errors.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Can you paste the error message?

Comment: Need some storyboard about using `LIMIT 1` while intending to delete one record :D

Comment: love that white screen error reporting.... if you change //include 'newsconnect.php';  and add die(1);  do you see 1?

Comment: no, blank screen again!

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Answer (score 3):

Missing a closing bracket:

```
include 'newsconnect.php';
$Id = $_POST['Id'];
if (empty($Id)) {
           //-^    
    echo 'please input an Post ID.';
} else {
    if (!$_POST['Submit']) {
        header('Location: http://www.hidensecrets.yourwebsolution.net/forum.php');
    } else {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM forum WHERE id = '$Id'") or die(mysql_error());
        header('Location: http://www.hidensecrets.yourwebsolution.net/forum.php');
        echo "Deleted!";
    }
}
```

Not sure which IDE you're using but most of them would show this error. You're also open to sql injection. [Find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) more.

Comment: i have placed the missing bracket but still encounter same problem

Comment: Check my edit. Try now. You had a `*` in the delete statement.

Comment: * removed, problem persists

Comment: Did you check if it's hitting the else where the delete is happening?

Comment: how would i go about doing that?>

Comment: Just echo anything before the `mysql_query` like `echo 'test';`

Answer (score 0):

What sort of issue are you facing? You're missing a closing parenthesis for `if (empty($Id) === true` in case the you're getting syntax error

Comment: Try turning on error reporting. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` before `include 'newsconnect.php';` and look for errors.

Comment: still displays blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must omit the asterisk in your delete query ! Try it and tell me the result :)

your code must use this query :

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM forum WHERE id = '$Id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

instead of this one :

```
mysql_query("DELETE * FROM forum WHERE id = '$Id'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Hope this it will be the solution :)

Comment: @Matt Brady your code must use this query :

mysql_query("DELETE FROM forum WHERE id = '$Id'") or die(mysql_error());

instead of this one :

mysql_query("DELETE * FROM forum WHERE id = '$Id'") or die(mysql_error());

Hope this it will be the solution :)